# Android listview with header layout

Tags: android

I am rephrasing my question. Please bear with me.

I have a `Cursor`, which has `carNum` and tasks needs to be done on that. So `carNum` repeats in table. Right now I am using `SimpleCursorAdapter` and displaying all the info as a `listitem`. What I would like to do is set `carNum` as a header of a list and tasks need to be done as `listitems`. In addition to this, I would like to make header it's own layout so that I can display `carNum` and some info about it. So now where should I start ?

How should I get distinct `carNum` from `Cursor` and make that as header ? And then get `listitem` for that ?

Here is the .java

```
public class MyTask extends Activity{

 String empid;
 ListView list;
 Cursor cursor = null; 
 TextView text;
 private  DbAdapter_Assignment assignment;

@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.listlayout); 
         empid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EmpID");
         getData(empid);
}

   public void getData(final String empid)
   {
        assignment =  new DbAdapter_Assignment(getBaseContext());
       assignment.open();

    cursor = assignment.getAcceptedTasks(empid);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeename);
    text.setText(getEmployeeName(empid) + " has "+ Integer.toString  (cursor.getCount()) + " tasks assigned." );
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mytasklist); 
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int arg2,
                long arg3) {         
        } 
   }); 

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.mytaskslayout, cursor, new String[] {"A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}, new int[] {R.id.a, R.id.b, R.id.c, R.id.d, R.id.e, R.id.f});
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Have you written any code so far? Can you post it please.

Comment: I am following http://kmansoft.com/2010/11/16/adding-group-headers-to-listview/ example, but fail to understand how can I get distinct carNum for header.

Comment: Well, you could start by creating a ListView of all the carNum (which I assume stands for car numbers?) and then worry about the other things. I suggest starting with something much simpler [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html), and [this tutorial](http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-listview-header-two-or-more-in.html). Then move on to your other issues.

Comment: Thanks for replying Andrei. As mentioned in the question I have a code for SimpleCursorAdapter which is populating a listview. In which, it's repeating carNum for some rows.

Comment: I suggest you add the code via edit and then I'm sure we'll be able to help from there.

Comment: @sam As you said, you have a problem with understanding which is difficult for someone else to help.  You'd better be more specific to get any help. But in this case, I would recommend try to follow the tutorial and narrow scope of your question down.

Comment: @Paul, I know what you are saying. I would like to know, in this case which Adapter is advisable. Using that Adapter, which methods to implement.

Comment: Well, since you are learning, maybe CursorAdapter may not be good to start with. If you are comfortable with BaseAdapter, you can start with inheriting that class and override getView where you might switch visibility of textview or listitem according to item's type. Of course, if you fully understand CursorAdapter, that's easier way.

Answer (score 0):

1. extend SimpleCursorAdapter
2. Build list of header indexes in the constructor

```
    c.moveToFirst();
    int headerIndex = -1;
    String headerValue = null;
    do {
         headerIndex++;
         String header = c.getString(getColumnClass());
         if (!header.equalsIgnoreCase(headerValue)) {
                    mHeaderIndexes.add(headerIndex);
                    headerValue = header;
                    headerIndex++;
          }
    }while (c.moveToNext());
    c.moveToFirst();
    mDataCount = c.getCount()+mHeaderIndexes.size();
```

3. Override methods

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mHeaderIndexes.contains(position)) {
            return TYPE_HEADER_ROW;
        }
        return TYPE_ROW;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if (mHeaderIndexes.contains(position)) {
            // for header row need return first row with data for this group
            getCursor().moveToPosition(position-mHeaderIndexes.indexOf(position));
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mHeaderIndexes.size(); i++) {
                if (mHeaderIndexes.get(i) > position) {
                    // need move back by number of headers before position
                    getCursor().moveToPosition(position - i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (position>mHeaderIndexes.get(mHeaderIndexes.size()-1)) {
                // if position is in the last group (position >last group header position)
                // move back by number of headers
                getCursor().moveToPosition(position - mHeaderIndexes.size());
            }
        }
        return getCursor();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return !mHeaderIndexes.contains(position);
    }
```

4. Implement getView()

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);

        View view = convertView;
        if (type==TYPE_HEADER_ROW) {
            boolean isHeader = view!=null && view.findViewById(R.id.title)!=null;
            if (!isHeader) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_my_header, null);
            }
            TextView header = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            header.setText(...);
        }
        else {
            if (view==null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_my_data, null);
            }
    // fill data row
         }
    return view;
    }
```